# What is the formula called that calculates the scales of things?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I use this formula all the time:

$$\frac{10}{100} = \frac{100}{x}$$

For example, the question may be, "if 10 apples equal 100 slices than 100 apples equals how many slices?"

Is there a name for this equation?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: I just know it as the proportionality equation or the means extremes property of proportion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication#Rule_of_Three

Comment: I call it scaling. (E.g. scaling slices by apples)  I used to think of it as "rationation", but apparently that isn't a word. (*It is now!* :-D )  Otherwise: algebra. I appreciate the "Rule of Three" answer from @HansLundmark there, although it seems like a terrible name to me.